# MySQL using LEFT or SUBSTRING in WHERE clause to increment duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, function, group-by, having

Inserting a title into a table, if it is a duplicate, I need to number it, such as
Title
Title 2
Title 3, etc.
I thought I could just compare the new title with those in the table by getting the length, then doing something like

```
"SELECT field FROM tablename WHERE LEFT(field,".$Length.") = '$NewTitle'"
```

then just count the rows and increment to create the new title and store it. Guess that's not legal.
Can't seem to find a simple solution. The entries come through an API, so I can't easily ask users to rename a title if it conflicts.

I tried

```
$NameLength = strlen($DocName);
    SELECT DocName, count(DocName) FROM Pickup GROUP BY DocName HAVING LEFT(DocName,'$NameLength') = '$DocName'";
```

So, if I have three titles, "Title"; "Title 2"; "Title 3", I thought I could then do

```
$D = mysql_fetch_array($Result);
$RCount = ($D[count(DocName)]) + 1;
$NewTitle = $DocName.' '.$RCount;
```

which works okay for the first conflict, creating "Title 2" but then will continue to create "Title 2"'s in subsequent entries.

Haven't quite wrapped my mind around this. I know it has to do with the distinctness of group by, but if I have one "title" and two title 2's and two title 3's, and I send another 'title, it will increment it to "title 4", the subsequent "Title"'s will also rename to "Title 4". Is it that Group By will not include anything that doesn't have a mate?

At any rate it is not a solution.

Comment: Sounds like Business logic, which should not be in DB layer

Comment: Another alternative would be to remove the unique option of the title.  If the titles can be duplicate, then allow that and find some other way of distinguishing between them.

Comment: I would have to restructure too much else to do that. This is a form, with a history function where previous entries can be pulled, used as templates, or partially filled and returned to later. A lot is based on the title the user gives to a record. The form has validation. No problem there. The API, on the other hand needs to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT((TRIM(SUBSTRING(`field`, LOCATE(' ', `name`) ))),UNSIGNED)) as count FROM `tablename` WHERE `field` LIKE 'Title%'
```

Comment: "Locate" good! I'll have to do some experimenting with this and get back with you.

Comment: Could not get this to work - perhaps partially do to my misunderstanding. At any rate, as you can see, I found a much simpler solution. "Having" is great when you want to use a function. But it must be accompanied with "Group By"

Comment: I was wrong. It wasn't a solution, am I am still searching.

Comment: you can always do 

SELECT COUNT(field) as count FROM `tablename` WHERE `field` LIKE 'Title%' 

$nextTitle = $title.' '.($row['count']+1);

------
as better solution I suggest you to make new column like 'version_of_document':

$version_of_document = ($row['count']+1);

Answer (score 0):

Let's say *title* is the title that you're searching for in the table.
You can get the count of records having title *title* by using query `"SELECT count fieldname FROM tablename fieldname = 'title'`.
If count is 0 then insert it the usual way otherwise increment count by 1 and append it to the *title* and then insert it.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because "Title 2" is not going to match "Title"